# How to return html from variable in fetch - React

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch

I would like to return the variable jsonData in textual form in the html. The code takes a link and from the fetch it gets the json that it should then print on the page, I just don't know how to do it.

```
  fetch(jsonlist)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((jsonData) => {
    if (jsonData !== null) {
      return jsonData;
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there anyone you can kindly help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use hooks like useEffect and useState to take over the async call

Try call api it in useEffect and once done set the data with setState